# Change cursor with getElementsByClass in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I want my cursor to be a hand when hovering over elements with a class of "one" after clicking a button. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function cursor()
    {
    document.getElementByClass("one").style.cursor="pointer";
    }
</script>
<h1 class="one">Mouse over this text!</h1>
</head>
<body>
<p class="fff">not me!</p>
<button type="button" onclick="cursor()">Change cursor</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It has only worked so far when I change it to getElementById("one") and changed one of the elements from a "one" class to a "one" id. Why is this not working with class as well?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it didn't work is because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node-list of multiple elements, which you have to access individually:

```
function cursor() {
    var elems = document.getElementByClass("one");
    for (var i=0, len=elems; i<len; i++) {
        elems[i].style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
}
```

But there really is no need to do this with JavaScript, use CSS:

```
.one {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the example really helped. But I will use the CSS

Comment: You really, *really* should! =) That's what it's *for*, to separate the presentation from the structure and the logic; and you are, of course, absolutely welcome, I'm glad to have been of (some) help! =)

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName() not document.getElementByClass

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using JavaScript here by using CSS.

```
.one {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The reason the JavaScript didn't automatically work is because `getElementById()` (if successful) returns a single reference to an element, of which you can set properties on.

The reason switching to `getElementsByClassName()` didn't automatically work is because it returns a `NodeList`, a collection of elements. This collection is like an array, and you must access its numbered properties to access the references to the elements it matched.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this at the time. Still, I am curious as to why it didn't work the way I had it?

Comment: @WillumMaguire I've added an explanation.